# Records or data are not save permanently in the Local Database in VB .net

Tags: vb.net

The Code is working perfectly and also reflected in the DataGridView which is also sourced in the local database. but when i run it again the new record is not reflected in the local database.

```vb
comm = conn.CreateCommand

comm.CommandText = "Insert into  tblServices Values('" & txtServiceID.Text & "', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', '" & txtQuantity.Text & "', '" & txtPrice.Text & "', '" & txtRemarks.Text & "', 1)"

comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your code and database used?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of records affected.  What is the result of that?  And also you need to read up on using parameters rather than string concatenation when constructing SQL commands

Comment: As suggested, the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` will tell you what's actually happening and thus what problem you actually need to solve. You should already know that and what that result is because, when things didn't work as expected, you should have read the documentation for that method. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation. There are only three possible outcomes: the call fails and an exception is thrown, the call succeeds and returns zero, or the call succeeds and returns a non-zero value. The last is the most likely, which means the data is being saved exactly as it should.

Comment: If the data is being saved exactly as it should then that means that you are either looking in the wrong database or the right database at the wrong time. To learn how local data files are managed, you should [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/archive/blogs/vsdata/debugging-with-local-database-file).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: 0

I Used a Local DB inside VB .Net. The one that can be found in Server Explorer enter image description here. the one that can be added as an item as Service-Based Database

Comment: I am not looking at the wrong database because when I Click the save button. and click the add button again i can noticed that the record counter increases. but when i close the program and run it again the changes is not reflected.

Comment: you can see the entire code below.

Comment: Thanks John, My program is now working Perfectly. it s now updating. Thank you all guys for sharing your thoughts and insights

Answer (score 0):

I Used a Local DB inside VB .Net. The one that can be found in Server Explorer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bDb9.png). the one that can be added as an item as Service-Based Database

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. Also don't use answers as ways to add further information to your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire code:

Public Class frmServices
Dim isAdding As Boolean
Dim isClosing As Boolean
Dim ServiceID As String
Private Sub frmServices_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
UpdateServicesView()
'Display_Data("tblServices", dgvServices)
End Sub

```
Public Sub setUpTextBox(bcolor As Color, clear As Boolean, enabled As Boolean)
    txtDescription.BackColor = bcolor
    txtQuantity.BackColor = bcolor
    txtPrice.BackColor = bcolor
    txtRemarks.BackColor = bcolor
    If clear = True Then
        txtDescription.Text = ""
        txtQuantity.Text = ""
        txtPrice.Text = ""
        txtRemarks.Text = ""
    End If
    txtServiceID.Enabled = False
    txtDescription.Enabled = enabled
    txtQuantity.Enabled = enabled
    txtPrice.Enabled = enabled
    txtRemarks.Enabled = enabled
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim count As Integer
    isAdding = True
    isClosing = True
    btnClose.Text = "&Cancel"
    btnAdd.Enabled = False
    btnSave.Enabled = True
    setUpTextBox(Color.White, True, True)
    Connect()
    Try
        comm = conn.CreateCommand
        comm.CommandText = "Select Count(ServiceID) from tblServices"

        count = comm.ExecuteScalar
        If count > 1000 Then
            txtServiceID.Text = "S-0" + count.ToString
        ElseIf count > 100 Then
            txtServiceID.Text = "S-00" + count.ToString
        ElseIf count > 10 Then
            txtServiceID.Text = "S-000" + count.ToString
        Else
            txtServiceID.Text = "S-0000" + count.ToString
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    If txtDescription.Text <> "" Or txtPrice.Text <> "" Or txtQuantity.Text <> "" Then
        Connect()

        If isAdding = True Then
            comm = conn.CreateCommand
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            comm.CommandText = "Insert into  tblServices Values('" & txtServiceID.Text & "', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', '" & txtQuantity.Text & "', '" & txtPrice.Text & "', '" & txtRemarks.Text & "', 1)"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Service Record Information had been saved", "Manalese Dental Clinic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            comm = conn.CreateCommand
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            comm.CommandText = "Update tblServices Set serviceDescription = '" & txtDescription.Text & "', quantity = '" & txtQuantity.Text & "', Price = '" & txtPrice.Text & "', Remarks = '" & txtRemarks.Text & "' Where ServiceId= '" & ServiceID & "'"
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Service Record Information had been updated", "Manalese Dental Clinic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If

        UpdateServicesView()
        setUpTextBox(Color.LightGray, True, False)
        isClosing = False
        isAdding = False
        resetButton(Me.btnAdd, Me.btnSave, Me.btnEdit, Me.btnDelete, Me.btnClose)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fiil-out Require Fields", "Manalese Dental Clinic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    isAdding = False
    btnSave.Enabled = True
    btnSave.Text = "&Update"
    btnClose.Text = "Cancel"
    btnEdit.Enabled = False
    setUpTextBox(Color.White, False, True)
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    comm = conn.CreateCommand
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    comm.CommandText = "Update tblServices Set Delete = 1 Where ServiceID = '" & ServiceID & "'"
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Service Record Information had been Deleted", "Manalese Dental Clinic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    If isClosing = False Then
        Me.Close()
    Else
        resetButton(Me.btnAdd, Me.btnSave, Me.btnEdit, Me.btnDelete, Me.btnClose)
        isAdding = False
        setUpTextBox(Color.LightGray, True, False)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvServices.CellContentClick
    ServiceID = dgvServices.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    txtDescription.Text = dgvServices.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    txtQuantity.Text = dgvServices.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    txtPrice.Text = dgvServices.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    txtRemarks.Text = dgvServices.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
    btnEdit.Enabled = True
    btnAdd.Enabled = False
    isClosing = True
    btnClose.Text = "&Cancel"
    btnDelete.Enabled = True

End Sub
Private Sub UpdateServicesView()
    Connect()
    dgvServices.Rows.Clear()
    comm = conn.CreateCommand
    comm.CommandText = "Select * from tblServices Where Deleted = 0"
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader
    Dim row As String()
    While reader.Read
        row = New String() {reader(0), reader(1), reader(2), reader(3), reader(4)}
        dgvServices.Rows.Add(row)
    End While
End Sub


Private Sub txtPrice_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPrice.KeyPress
    If txtPrice.Text.Contains(".") And Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And Not Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Then
        e.Handled = True
    ElseIf Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = True OrElse Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 OrElse e.KeyChar = "." Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtQuantity_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtQuantity.KeyPress
    If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = True OrElse Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If

    'e.Handled = Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
End Sub

Private Sub txtPrice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPrice.TextChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This code is working does not contain any error. but the data is not permanently saved.